# Adding a background to a cropped canvas area

Tags: jquery, canvas, crop

I'm attempting to work with Resizing and cropping script from
[Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/)

It's very good however if the image does not fill the cropping area the script fails and all the image turns black.

My thoughts are to maybe create a solid image first then apply the cropped image on top. But I'm struggling.

I'm guessing somewhere around here:

```
    var crop_canvas,
    left = $('.size_guide').offset().left - $container.offset().left,
    top =  $('.size_guide').offset().top - $container.offset().top,
    width = $('.size_guide').width(),
    height = $('.size_guide').height();

crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');


crop_canvas.width = width;
crop_canvas.height = height;



crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
```

Any ideas on to how to go about this or try a different solution?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they missed a bounds check when drawImaging the image_target.

You can do the bounds correction for them like this:

```
if(left<0){left=0;}
if(top<0){top=0;}
if(width>image_target.width){width=image_target.width;}
if(height>image_target.height){height=image_target.height;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example they apply a background-repeating image with css to the div with the class "component"

```
 background: url(../img/gridme.png) repeat center center;
```

If you want to, you could add a background-image. If you pick a neutral white repeating pattern it should work? If that doesn't it might be best to try to make a fiddle so we can see where the jquery problem lies.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to make a difference, if you try their demo (making the image smaller than the 'cropbox') it still fails and does not return a cropped image.